# Multidimensional array to csv - how to create a second csv line for nested arrays

Tags: php

I'm working with the following array.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [application_id] => 5234324
        [edition] => Enterprise
        [build_number] => 12.1.0.2.0
        [product] => Array
            (
                [vendor] => Oracle
                [name] => Oracle Database Server
            )

        [devices] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [device_id] => 432432
                        [host_name] => node1
                        [serial_number] => hs3423523d
                        [manufacturer] => HP
                        [model] => ProLiant DL380 Gen9
                        [last_scan] => 2018-04-27 11:39:51
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [device_id] => 4ccf834b-43fa-4dd4-925a-9a3c96fadaf4
                        [host_name] => node2
                        [serial_number] => fdsgs35ed
                        [manufacturer] => HP
                        [model] => ProLiant DL380 Gen9
                        [last_scan] => 2018-04-27 08:24:08
                    )

            )


        [version] => 12c

    )

)
```

Below is my code to create a cleaner array and then write the line to a single CSV file.

```
$array = json_decode($result, true);

$applicationid = $data['application_id']?? '';
$softwareedition = $data['edition']?? '';
$buildnumber = $data['build_number']?? '';
$hostname = $data['devices'][0]['host_name']?? '';
$applicationversion = $data['version']?? '';

$device_array = array($applicationid, $softwareedition, $buildnumber, 
$hostname,$location, $location, $lastscan, $applicationversion);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'a');

fputcsv($fp, $device_array);

fclose($fp);
```

This works great and the code writes the following line to the CSV file.

5234324,Enterprise,12.1.0.2.0,node1,12c

What I can't figure out is how to write a second CSV line as this particular array has two hostnames. So for such an array I would like to write two lines like this

5234324,Enterprise,12.1.0.2.0,node1,12c

5234324,Enterprise,12.1.0.2.0,node2,12c

I found the array_key_exists function but it doesn't work with multidimensional arrays. Would some pseudo code work best here? Something like this inside an inner loop.

GET HostnameCount
i = 0
WHILE i < HostnameCount...

Any help would be appreciated.